# How to match one word or another in Elisp regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have a string contains html code, as below:

```
...
<a href="../link.png">image link</a>
...
<img src="../image.png" />
...
<pre class="should_not_match">...</pre>
...
```

I want to extract all resource paths: `../link.png` of `href` in `a`, and also `../image.png` of `src` in `img`. Now I have the following code:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert html-content) ;; html-content is the content mentioned above
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while (re-search-forward "<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+[src|href]=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>" nil t)
    (message (match-string 1))
    ;; more code here
    ))
```

The output includes not only wanted `../link.png`, `../image.png`, but also `should_not_match`, I know it is because the incorrect `[src|href]` in regexp (I want to match either `src` or `href`). Then I use the following regexp:

```
"<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+(src|href)=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>"
```

But it returns `nil` now. I also tried the following, but without luck:

```
"<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+\\(src|href\\)=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>"
"<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+((src)|(href))=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>"
"<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+(\\(src\\)|\\(href\\))=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>"
"<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+\\((src)|(href)\\)=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>"
"<[a-zA-Z]+[^/>]+\\(\\(src\\)|\\(href\\)\\)=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]*>"
```

So, what is the exactly correct regexp that can work?

Thanks in advance,
Kelvin

---

**EDIT**

Inspired by @lawlist, I find it is because I need to escape `|` with `\\|`, so `\\(src\\|href\\)` works well.

Comment: Something like this?  `\\(<a href=\"\\|<img src=\"\\)\\(.*\\)\\(\">image link</a>\\|\" />\\)`

Comment: If you haven't tried, `M-x re-builder`, you'll enjoy it.  Just paste your sample html code in the primary buffer and then paste your proposed regexp between the quotation marks in the re-builder buffer.  Each region matched gets highlighted in a different color, and you can play around with the regexp in the re-builder buffer to see whether or not it creates a match.  In my example, the *second* region matches `../link.png` and `../image.png`

Comment: @lawlist Oh, thanks for your regexp, it reminded me that the `|` needs to escape... So, it should be `\\(src\\|href\\)` and it works, stupid mistake... And also, thanks for the command `re-builder`, I never know it before, it is really helpful. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular regexp covers the first two items in the example of the original poster, e.g, `<a href="../link.png">image link</a>` and `<img src="../image.png" />`.  I saw no need to exclude the third item in the example of the original poster because it is not included in the following regexp:

```
\\(<a href=\"\\|<img src=\"\\)\\(.*\\)\\(\">image link</a>\\|\" />\\)
```

The regexp of the original poster does not cover a portion of the first example -- i.e., `image link</a>` is not contemplated by the regexp even if we fix `\\(src\\|href\\)`.  Thus, my recommendation would be to devise a regexp that includes the entire html link.

Answer (score 0):

how about something simpler like :

> (src|href)=".*"

Tested this in http://regexpal.com/

Comment: In fact, I have fixed it, it is because in elisp regexp, the `|` should be escaped, as `\\|`, however, thank you very much.